# Strange Linear Dependence Conjecture

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Recently I've came across the following conjecture:

Let $P(x), Q(x), R(x)$ be polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ with degree $n$. Then the $\binom{n+2}{2}$ polynomials $P(x)^j Q(x)^k R(x)^l$ where $j+k+l=n$ and $j,k,l$ are nonnegative integers are linearly dependent.

My approach is as follows: I first assumed that $P(x), Q(x)R(x)$ don't share roots. Furthermore, if $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ are the roots of $P$ and $q_j = Q(p_j), r_j = R(p_j)$ then $\frac{q_j}{r_j}$ are distinct. Through $Q(x)^k R(x)^{n-k}$ I can construct a multiple of $P(x)$ (which I have shown is unique), and via that multiple and $P(x)Q(x)^k R(x)^{n-1-k}$ I have constructed a multiple of $P(x)^2$ (which is unique) and so on, so on. My method of constructing is by focusing $A(p_1), \cdots, A(p_n)$ for a polynomial $A$. I ended up constructing a polynomial a low degree polynomial with $n$ given points. I can share more details later.

Comment: If you consider the vector space of polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ with degree at most $n$, then you can see any set of $n+1$ polynomials is linearly dependent (since the dimension of the vector space is $n+1$). So this would hold for this set of $\binom{n+2}{2}$ polynomials as well.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I think that argument does not quite work. The product of polyomials has degree $n^2$. The space of degree polynomials of degree at most $n^2$ has dimension $n^2+1$, but $\binom{n-1}{2}=\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}$ does not exceed the dimension (note that we require the powers to be nonnegative, so really, we can only distribute $n-3$ powers freely).

Comment: Ah you're right. For some reason, I thought the degrees of $P(x)^jQ(x)^kR(x)^l$ would be $n$, which obviously isn't true.